# Accepting a list either of strings or (str, dict) tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that accepts a list-like of tuples and iterates over it:

```py
def fn(arglist):
  for col, extra in arglist:
    # do stuff with col, extra
```

Here `col` is expected to be a string, and `extra` is a dict of extra arguments.

*Usually* `extra` ends up being empty, so one is often calling this function like so:

```
fn(arglist=[ ('foo', {}), ('bar', {}), ('baz', {}) ])
```

I'd like to change `fn` so that it can accept *either* a list of tuple-likes (as above), or a plain list of strings, which would allow you to make the same call as above simply as:

fn(arglist=[ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'])

How do I change `fn` to do the same iteration but with an empty dict in the case strings are passed?

I could explicitly check if the elements are iterable, something like:

```py
def fn(arglist):
  for maybe_tuple in arglist:
    if isinstance(obj, Iterable):
      col, extra = maybe_tuple
    else:
      col, extra = maybe_tuple, {}
```

... but this seems pretty awkward. What's more pythonic way to handle the tuple and non-tuple cases in a combined way here?

Comment: That won't actually work - strings are *also* iterable.

Comment: Just check if the item is a string instance.

Comment: one possibility is to check the type of your arguments using `type(arglist[0])` and `type(arglist[1])` and convert the arguments accordingly ?

Answer (score 1):

this is a little more pythonic, but having this situation is a "code smell" imho

```
def fn(arglist):
  for arg in arglist:
    try:
      col, extra = arg
    except ValueError:
      col, extra = arg, {}
    # do stuff with col, extra
```

Comment: I encounter this pattern (polymorphic lists as arguments) all the time in Python libraries. How would you suggest I remove the smell?

Comment: well, polymorphic lists are more often used with element that "look the same" (eg: file like object, string like object, ...). Basically they have a common interface.
Here you have different beast (string vs tuple)
But it depends of your use case. If this work for you, go with this ! :-)